# TextFieldParser Delimiter not recognizing string

Tags: vb.net

Think its simple straightforward, but i can't figure out why having something like this below

```
Dim MyDelimeter as string = "vbTab"
MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {MyDelimeter }
```

its not recognizing MyDelimeter as tab. If i would have comma its working.

```
Dim MyDelimeter as string = ","
```

Can you explain why its happen? My delimeters are from xml serialized file so i would like to put them unfortunetly its not working for vbtab.

Comment: `"vbTab" is a string literal.  I doubt your file has "vbtab" littered everywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}
```

instead of

```
MyReader.Delimiters = New String() { "vbTab" }
```

[`vbTab`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.constants.vbtab%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a visual basic constant for the tab character whereas the string literal `"vbTab"` is just the text `"vbTab"`.

If you have stored the value `"vbTab"` in a file to indicate the delimiter which should be used you have to use `If...Else` or `Select..Case` to use the `vbTab` constant. Of course you could also store the real tab character in the file, but i guess that you don't want that because it's not really visible.

For example

```
If delimiterInFile = "vbTab" Then
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {vbTab}
ElseIf delimiterInFile = "comma" Then
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
ElseIf delimiterInFile = "pipe" Then
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {"|"}
    ' ....
Else
    MyReader.Delimiters = New String() {","}
End If
```

Comment: i know this but how to put my string which is comming out from xml serialized file   and representing which delimeter has to be used to MyReader.Delimiters ?

Comment: @unknown: i have edited my answer. You have to use an `If..else` or `Select.`

Comment: i did exactly as you posted :) It almost what i would like to have but anyhow i would like to create additional class and method inside it that would return New String() {..} based on what i pass to it from my serialized xml. The problem is what my further method should be returned as type if most of delimeters are string then i would return string but whats then in case of vbTab i cannot return it as string.

Comment: @unknown: i'm afraid that you've lost me there, `vbTab` _is_ a `String`.